# What value can not be changed in /proc/sys?

Tags: linux

What value can not be changed in /proc/sys?

```
echo "Windows" > /proc/sys/kernel/ostype
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/ostype: Permission denied
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ostype don't have write permission:

```
ls -al /proc/sys/kernel/ostype
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2011-02-25 05:20 /proc/sys/kernel/ostype
```

If file in /proc/sys/ have write permission, you can change values in it.

Answer (score 7):

The real answer to this question is really to understand what the [proc filesystem means](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Procfs).  `/proc` isn't a real filesystem - it's a filesystem interface to system internals.  When you're reading or writing things in /proc you aren't reading or writing to or from the disk - you're reading and writing directly into things lie kernel memory or device drivers.

Thus yes the basic answer to 'why can't I write to `/proc/sys/kernel/ostype`?' is that the `file` isn't writable.  However, the more complete answer is that this particular file is presented to you as read-only because it wouldn't make any sense to change it.  'ostype' is an immutable property of a running system.

Comment: Phil: a lovely example of a "bigger picture" answer, informative, accurate and well-referenced.  I commend it to the OP (and to others!).